# no \bibdata and no \bibstyle found in main.aux

Tags: biblatex, biber

Simply I can not compile my bibliography file. How can I fix this issue?

```
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command-
```

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04. This is the first time I am trying to use texmaker on Ubuntu. I did not face this issue with Windows 7. This template is taken from somewhere else.

```
    %\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
%\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}


%\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lscape}
\hyphenation{de-pen-dent}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}


% WORKS
%\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{
  \small\ttfamily\bfseries\catcode`\<=\active\catcode`\>=\active
}
\makeatother  


\begin{document}

\title{title here}


\IEEEcompsoctitleabstractindextext{

\begin{abstract}
ABSTRACT HERE
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
[TODO]
\end{keywords}}

\maketitle

\IEEEdisplaynotcompsoctitleabstractindextext

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

%\input{intro}
%\input{background}
%\input{methodology}
%\input{experiments}
%\input{threats}
%\input{related}
%\input{conclusion}


%\section{Acknowledgments} 

\small
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\normalsize

\appendices
%\input{appendices}

\end{document}
```

You may think that there are lots of duplicates but believe me I am searching google and stackowerflow for hours. Nothing worked.

Comment: Well, don't use the cite package with biblatex. You don't need it, since biblatex comes with own cite commands.

Comment: Sorry but what is not understable when an error says "incompatible package"? Remove the cite package, it doesn't work with biblatex (and is also unnecessary). Remove also the `\bibliography{main.bib} ` at the end. Replace it by \printbibliography.

Comment: Sorry guys. I made a big mistake. My error was not that, I am changing question now.

Comment: then also modify your MWE since it still includes the cite package...

Comment: you should really go over your MWE and reduce it to the really needed packages which show the problem. I won't install 15 packages :P

Comment: did you try to delete all auxiliary files and recompile it? how does your compiliation process look like? pdflatex - biber - pdflatex - pdflatex?

Comment: @musicman I reduced them now :)

Comment: compilation process does not include biber, it is not included in the list. Instead biber, I have bibtex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15514/discussion-between-musicman-and-genclik27).

Comment: put `\nocite{*}` before `\printbibliography`

Comment: Did not work :( @Herbert

Comment: It needs two runs

Comment: In quick build, I have already; pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex. @Herbert

Comment: for `bibtex` the setting `backend=biber,` is wrong

Comment: I updated the code, not working again. @Herbert

Comment: You have to run **Biber**, not **BibTeX**

Comment: But there is no option for biber @egreg

Comment: Unless you tell ***what*** front end you're using for processing the files, it's impossible to help.

Comment: see the chat, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15514/discussion-between-musicman-and-genclik27 I've already explained him/her a lot